# NHD-0216HZ-FSW-FBW-33V3C Black Boxes in Line LCD Display

Tags: assembly, msp430, lcd

I installed a NHD-0216HZ-FSW-FBW-33V3C with an MSP430g2553. I tried to initialize it for 4-bit mode in assembly language but black boxes still shown and initialization is not completed I think.

My connections are: DB4-DB7 --> P1.4-P1.7 respectively, RS --> P2.0, R/W --> P2.1, Enable --> P2.2

Here is my code:

```
Init:     bic.b     #0xFF,P1OUT  ;Clear P1, P1 = 0
          bis.b     #0x01,&P2OUT ;High RS = 1
          bic.b     #0x01,&P2OUT ;Clear RS = 0
          call      #Delay100ms
          mov.b     #0x30,&P1OUT 
          call      #Nibble      ;Wake up 1
          call      #Delay10ms 
          call      #Nibble      ;Wake up 2
          call      #Delay10ms       
          mov.b     #0x20,P1OUT
          call      #Nibble      ;Wake up 3
          call      #Command28
          call      #Command10
          call      #Command0F
          call      #Command06
          ret

Nibble    bis.b      #0x04,&P2OUT ;Enable High
          call       #Delay1ms
          bic.b      #0x04,&P2OUT ;Clock Enable - Falling Edge
          ret
Command28     mov.b     #0x28,&P1OUT //Data in port
          bic.b     #1,&P2OUT    //RS = 0 : Send Instruction
          bic.b     #0x02,&P2OUT //R/W = 0 : Write
          call      #Nibble      //Send Lower 4 Bits
          mov.b     #0x28,R4
          push      R4
          mov.b     #4,R5       ;Rotate Left Counter
C28           rla.b     R4
          dec       R5
          jnz       C28
          mov.b     R4,&P1OUT   //put data in output port
          call      #Nibble     //Send upper 4 bits
          pop       R4
          and.b     #0xF0,R4
          mov.b     R4,&P1OUT
          ret
```

This code is following the code in the NHD-0216HZ-FSW-FBW-33V3C datasheet from [LCD Display Datasheet](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-0216HZ-FSW-FBW-33V3C.pdf). If someone can help me.